# How to measure capacitance of soil without being affected by resistance?

Tags: oscillator, measurement, capacitance

I want to make a capacitive soil moisture detector. Capacitance of soil increases with increasing moisture content. Resistance of soil decreases with increasing moisture content. The soil capacitance is considered a more accurate indicator of the moisture level.

If I have 2 capacitance plates buried in the soil what general type of circuit can I use to measure just the capacitance?

I know that these type of detectors use about 10MHz sine wave across the plates, but I can't find more detailed circuit information online.

I though perhaps the soil capacitance would be used with a fixed inductance to make an oscillator. Then the frequency of the oscillator would be related to the soil capacitance.

Comment: Um.. insulate the plates with something so there is no conduction through the soil....

Comment: Look for "insulating varnish" like they use on magnet wire.

Comment: Haha, yes that sounds obvious, I'm just not used to thinking of capacitors this way. I would still like to know how to do the rest of the circuit. I imagine it will be quite small a capacitance because it would be nice to get the plates as far apart as possible to read moisture in a large space (about 25 litres)

Comment: Would there still be the issue that the water would kind of create a short across the dielectric? Maybe that is why higher frequencies are used.

Comment: Completely isolate the plates as @Trevor wrote. No one uses plates, but two copper traces next to each other on a single plate. The plates should be only a few millimeters apart. Expect a capacitance of about 50pF. This is open source: https://wemakethings.net/chirp/

Comment: And yes water in the soil will affect the dielectric properties... but then, isn't that what you are trying to measure?

Comment: That is useful, I was hoping to measure a large volume of soil, maybe that is too ambitious as it would involve very small capacitance. Even if the plates are completely insulated the resistance of the dielectric might still an effect, depending what type of circuit is used.

Comment: The dielectric has permittivity and resistance, normally we don't need to thick about dielectric resistance because it is usually very high. I would prefer to just measure the permittivity.

Comment: @NickCollier ya but I don't think you can if you want to measure moisture content since if the solid is saturated you are basically working with salty water as the dielectric. If you wanted to know the capacitance of the soil alone, you would need to dry the soil first. This is an XY problem. ANyhow... it has already been done, see Jot's comment.

Comment: Thank you, I can see it has been done. I would need to test this approach to see if it works well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magazine RF Design provided circuit for inductance meter, many years ago.
Ran at 100,000Hz and used NE602 double-balanced mixer that cancelled both the RF input and the LO input, leaving only the differential sum+difference energy as the output.

Given real inductors have losses (real) in addition to the energy-storage (reactive) component, that meter used a precise quadrature source of current, imposed across Kelvin force-sense terminal pairs.

I redesigned the meter to run at 10MHz, with full scale of 1,000 nanoHenries, for measuring very small inductors and some PCB parasitics. The terminals were 1cm squares of PCB material, with "force" on one edge, "sense" on opposite edge, and the "test point" the intervening orthogonal edge.

For a capacitance meter, take the opposing approach: there is no DC path needed, thus a **VOLTAGE** is needed. You must extract the real and the quadrature components; The "capacitor" will induce 90 degrees; the losses will be inphase.

Comment: Thank you I will consider that approach if it is necessary, it might be overkill. Do you have any link to this type of circuit. Do I just need a quadrature detector? Not a quadrature input signal?

Comment: In the 10MHz inductance meter, I used a trim-cap to implement a phaseshifter (which also had variable losses); the trimcap setting was set with a resistor in place of the inductor, and the trimcap was tweaked for ZERO indicated inductance. Then the "gain" was tweaked with a 1uH inductor, to indicate fullscale.